# ARCore for Android

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am going to develop a project in AR.  All other kits are paid instead of ARCore by Google. Should I choose it for my project. As it was launched in previous year.

I am trying to run a demo called augmented faces provided by Google. I run it on three devices. On two devices. I got redirected to play store to update ARCore. But it is showing : This device is not compatible with this version. I did many tricks available on Google but nothing worked. In third device it shows a toast for openGL 3 or above is required. Save in emulator.

Please answer my question Thank You.

Comment: Which devices are you testing on? List of supported devices: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

Comment: I am testing on Moto g4 plus,

Comment: I have tested other AI apps. On same device they work perfectly.

Comment: Moto g4 plus not supported in list for ARCore. Only Google can update the supported device list inside the Google Play Store version of ARCore. If you want to make it easy for yourself when Google adds new features, get a supported phone.

Comment: Okay, do this means ARCore will work on the devices listed in supported devices?

Comment: If yes, is there any way ? Through which we can run ARCore on not supported devices? And one more thing I want to know is, Some applications ARCore works on Moto G4 plus.

Comment: Are they using some other AR library? And is ARCore by Google good to choose for my project.

Comment: Other apps will use their own library and have resources to support publishers like [Facebook's Spark AR Studio](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio) but those custom face effects only lives within Facebook and/or Instagram.

Comment: Okay, That means if I choose ARCore. I cannot do anything for the users having unsupported devices.

Comment: And I also want to know one more thing. I want to learn unity and ARCore. Should I learn both for good growth in my carrier. And I found tutorials of ARCore and Unity. Should I buy tutorials with unity only first and then go for ARCore and Unity tutorials. Or should I start with ARCore and Unity tutorials.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201731/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-vabhi-vab).